# Задача для изучение паттерна MVC и Dependency Injection

Tags: php, slim

Хочу начать изучать микрофреймворк Slim, разобраться с паттерном mvc и поработать с каким-нибудь DI-контейнером.

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какие-то классические задачи, или может вы знаете какие-то задачи, решая которые по ходу работы можно будет хорошо поработать на практике с DI контейнерами, middleware и т.д. ?

Comment: у вас наверняка будет БД и скорее всего это будет `mysql`, а что вы будете делать, если вам потребуется переключиться на `postgresql` - вот вам задача на DI)